# Array of string in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Hello I need to show the array of strings in XSD. I've tried this, Can any one help me write it correctly. Thanks.

What it prints

```
<numbers>13 32 23</numbers>
```

Current XSD

```
<xs:element name="numbers" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> 
    <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:list itemType="xs:string">                                                     

          </xs:list>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

What I need is below.

```
<numbers>
   <number>13</number><number>32</number>
</numbers>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="numbers">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="number" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

numbers would be a complex typed-element, accepting element only content.

Answer (score 9):

The question is resolved since Petru's answer is correct. I just want to add some additional information I found related with this same topic about how to define array types, optional and mandatory:

### Primitive types

```
 <xsd:element name="A"/>
```

means A is **required** and must **appear exactly once**.

```
<xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="0"/>
```

means A is **optional** and **may appear at most once**.

### Arrays/Lists

```
<xsd:element name="A" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

means A is **required** and **may repeat an unlimited number of times**

```
<xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

means A is **optional** and **may repeat an unlimited number of times**